# How to SUM DataGrid column and show result in TextBox, label or a Grid footer in VB.net WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How to SUM DataGrid column and show result in textbox, label or grid footer in vb.net WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataTable.Compute method assuming the dgv uses a datatable as datasource (usually thats good info to post).

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim MySumObj As Object = dt.Compute("SUM(ColumnName)", Nothing)
    TextBox1.Text = If(MySumObj IsNot Nothing, CInt(MySumObj), 0)
```